# What happens in <c:out> tag?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a piece of code in my html which prints the output

```
<div> <c:out value="${cart.headline}"> Your page is here </c:out>
```

I know that in the above case, the value of cart.headline will be printed. But when will the content between c:out tags be printed or used.

Can someone please explain ?

Comment: On the serverside, before the output is sent to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<c:out>` tag displays the result of an expression, similar to the way `<%= %>` works with a difference that `<c:out>` tag lets you use the simpler `"."` notation to access properties. 
For example, to access `cart.headline` just use tag is `<c:out value="cart.headline"/>`.

The `<c:out>` tag can automatically escape XML tags so they aren't evaluated as actual tags.

something [useful](http://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/standard/apidocs/) here.

Hope this helps!!